# is it true that there are infinitely many primes $P$ of the form $p_0^{\alpha_0}p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k}+1$?

Tags: number-theory

It is known that for any two positive coprime integers $a$ and $d$, there are infinitely many primes of the form $a + nd$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer. This is known as the Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.

So I am wondering, given $k+1$ different prime numbers: $p_0,p_1,...,p_k$, with $p_0=2$ and $k>0$, is it true that there are infinitely many primes $P$ such that all prime divisors of $P-1$ are only $p_0,p_1,...,p_k$ ? In other words, is it true that there are infinitely many primes $P$ of the form $p_0^{\alpha_0}p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k}+1$ ?

(Please let me know if this question is off-topic or should be closed)

Comment: It is probably not known. For $k=0$ the question becomes "Are there infinitely many primes of the form $2^\alpha+1$?", which is an open problem. See Fermat's numbers, or Fermat's primes.

Comment: "what about k>0 ?" You might have missed the intent of @ajotatxe's comment: what they are saying is that for no $k$ is this known, probably, and that **already** for $k=0$ it is not known.

Comment: @Did Sorry for my mistakes. I have deleted my comment.