# is it true that there **exist at least** a prime $P$ of the form $p_0^{\alpha_0}p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k}+1$ ?

Tags: number-theory

Given $k+1$ different prime numbers: $p_0,p_1,...,p_k$, with $p_0=2$ and $k>0$, is it true that there **exist at least** a prime $P$ such that all prime divisors of $P-1$ are only $p_0,p_1,...,p_k$ ? In other words, is it true that there is a prime $P$ of the form $p_0^{\alpha_0}p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k}+1$ ?

I know this should be an open problem if I asked there exist infinitely many primes $P$ (I have asked here: [is it true that there are infinitely many primes $P$ of the form $p_0^{\alpha_0}p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k}+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039371/is-it-true-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-p-of-the-form-p-0-alpha-0?noredirect=1#comment6266689_3039371) , I may delete this question), since it is unclear whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $2^\alpha +1$ or not (Fermat's prime). However, there is a least a prime of the form $2^\alpha +1$, is $5$.

(Please let me know if this question is off-topic or should be closed)